# A consumable byte array, in Swift

Tags: swift, serialization

For decoding binary data (in my case, delivered by a Bluetooth device), I've written this struct:

```
public struct ConsumableByteArray {
    private let bytes: [UInt8]
    private var idx = 0

    enum Error: Swift.Error {
        case notEnoughBytes
    }

    init(data: Data) {
        bytes = [UInt8](data)
    }

    init(bytes: [UInt8]) {
        self.bytes = bytes
    }

    mutating func consume() throws -> UInt8 {
        guard idx < bytes.count else {
            throw Error.notEnoughBytes
        }
        defer { idx += 1}
        return bytes[idx]
    }

    mutating func consume() throws -> UInt16 {
        guard idx+1 < bytes.count else {
            throw Error.notEnoughBytes
        }
        defer { idx += 2 }
        return UInt16(bytes[idx+1]) << 8 + UInt16(bytes[idx])
    }

    mutating func consume() throws -> Int16 {
        guard idx+1 < bytes.count else {
            throw Error.notEnoughBytes
        }
        defer { idx += 2 }
        return Int16(bytes[idx+1]) << 8 + Int16(bytes[idx])
    }

    mutating func consume() throws -> UInt32 {
        guard idx+3 < bytes.count else {
            throw Error.notEnoughBytes
        }
        defer { idx += 4 }
        // Swift compiler insists on splitting this expression up
        let b3 = UInt32(bytes[idx+3]) << 24
        let b2 = UInt32(bytes[idx+2]) << 16
        let b1 = UInt32(bytes[idx+1]) << 8
        let b0 = UInt32(bytes[idx+0]) << 0

        return b3 + b2 + b1 + b0
    }
}
```

Given some data buffer, likely containing `int`s of varying widths packed together, it allows those fields to be read out:

```
let buffer = ConsumableByteArray(data: someData)
let header:UInt8 = try buffer.consume()
let word1:UInt16 = try buffer.consume()
let word2:UInt16 = try buffer.consume()
let crc32:UInt32 = try buffer.consume()
```

Values in the early data may alter the structure of the later data (e.g. whether a feature is supported or not), hence the need for the flexibility to extract data progressively.

Would you write the implementation any differently, or change the API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of implementing `consume()` for each integer type separately,
you can implement a *single generic* method:

```
mutating func consume<T: FixedWidthInteger & UnsignedInteger>() throws -> T {
    let size = MemoryLayout<T>.size
    guard idx + size <= bytes.count else {
        throw Error.notEnoughBytes
    }
    defer { idx += size }
    return bytes[idx..<idx + size].enumerated().reduce(0) {
        $0 + T($1.element) << (8 * $1.offset)
    }
}
```

which can be used for all unsigned integer types `UInt`, `UInt8`, ..., `UInt64`, e.g.

```
let header: UInt8 = try buffer.consume()
```

and for the signed integer types via the `bitPattern:` initializer, e.g.

```
let word = try! Int16(bitPattern: buffer.consume())
```

Another option is to copy the bytes into a value of the desired type
instead of bit shifting and adding:

```
mutating func consume<T: FixedWidthInteger>() throws -> T {
    let size = MemoryLayout<T>.size
    guard idx + size <= bytes.count else {
        throw Error.notEnoughBytes
    }
    var value: T = 0
    bytes.withUnsafeBytes { _ = memcpy(&value, $0.baseAddress! + idx, size) }
    idx += size
    return T(littleEndian: value)
}
```

---

Instead of letting the compiler infer the return type from the context,
one can alternatively pass it as a parameter:

```
mutating func consume<T: FixedWidthInteger>(_: T.Type) throws -> T { ... }
```

which is then – for example – called as

```
let crc32 = try buffer.consume(UInt32.self)
```

---

I would probably call the method `get()` or `read()` instead of `consume()`.

---

Defining a local `enum Error` type which conforms to the (global)
`Error` protocol is possible, but might be confusing to the reader.
I would use a different name for the concrete error type, for example:

```
enum ReadError: Error {
    case notEnoughBytes
}
```

---

Now let's have a look how an error would be reported.
The caller does not know the actual error type, so a typical calling
sequence is:

```
do {
    let someData = Data(bytes: [1])
    var buffer = ConsumableByteArray(data: someData)
    let crc32: UInt32 = try buffer.consume()
    print(crc32)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

This produces the output:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (MyProg.ConsumableByteArray.ReadError error 0.)
```

This can be improved by adopting the `LocalizedError` protocol
(see for example [How to provide a localized description with an Error type in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39176196/1187415) on
Stack Overflow):

```
enum ReadError: Error, LocalizedError {
    case notEnoughBytes

    public var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .notEnoughBytes:
            return "Not enough bytes in buffer"
        }
    }
}
```

Now the error output of the above program becomes

```
Not enough bytes in buffer
```

You can even store additional information about the error in associated
values:

```
enum ReadError: Error, LocalizedError {
    case notEnoughBytes(available: Int, needed: Int)

    public var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .notEnoughBytes(let available, let needed):
            return "Not enough bytes in buffer (available: \(available), needed: \(needed))"
        }
    }
}
```

Then by throwing

```
 throw ReadError.notEnoughBytes(available: bytes.count - idx, needed: size)
```

an error message like

```
Not enough bytes in buffer (available: 1, needed: 4)
```

is produced.

---

Finally note that there is a [`ByteBuffer`](https://apple.github.io/swift-nio/docs/current/NIO/Structs/ByteBuffer.html) type as part of the 
[SwiftNIO](https://github.com/apple/swift-nio) framework,
which can do all this and more. Even if you decide not to use it,
having a look at its documentation and interface might be instructive.

Comment: Some great suggestions in there - I particularly like the generic one-size-fits-all change. (As you may have noticed, I'd only implemented for the types I'd encountered so far). I think I picked the `enum Error: Swift.Error` up from https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/picking-the-right-way-of-failing-in-swift, but I will rethink/revisit the whole error reporting aspect.

Comment: Your suggestions and the style in which you presented them are greatly appreciated - I've adopted the shift and add version.

Comment: The `.reduce(0) {
        $0 + T($1.element) << (8 * $1.offset)
    }` version (my preference as it's more Swift-y) fails for signed Int8's with a value in the byte buffer > 127 as "Not enough bits to represent a signed value". If there's a neat way of resolving this, it's not apparent to me.

Comment: @Chris: You are right, *that* generic method works properly only with unsigned integer types. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt update. It's a shame the caller has to do extra/different work in the signed case, but I can see no alternative.